# Task creating another Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

```
for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
{
    Task<myObject>.Run(() => 
    {
       // some work
       // ...
       Task<myObjectNew>.Run(() => { // other work });
    });
}
```

I have a loop which creates lots of initial tasks (say upto 100). Then each of these tasks does some small unit of work and then creates another task itself. What I am noticing is that non of the initial 100 tasks start until all have been setup.

If the initial Task creates a Thread as opposed to another Task then things seem fine and as soon as the first outer task is created it begins executing (and spawns off a new Thread etc).

I've not seen behavior like before but then again I've not had a Task create another Task.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're just calling Task.Run and want to start immediately, using the TPL seems to be only adding unnecessary overhead and confusion; have you considered keeping it simple and just call `new Thread(...).Start()`?

Comment: @DaxFohl Could you please explain how it introduces overhead?

Comment: Perhaps attempt to explain what your end goal is. There are alot of abstractions (such as `TPL Dataflow`, for example) that may help you out with thread scheduling instead of rolling it out on your own.

Comment: @Science_Fiction, you may want to try tweaking `ThreadPool`: `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(200, 200); ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` Although as others say, there's probably a better approach than what you're using.

Comment: @yuri task is a layer on top of thread, so how does it not?

Answer (score 1):

The `Task<T>` objects are managed through the thread pool, and are limited in terms of how quickly they are started. I don't recall the current defaults off the top of my head, but the basic idea is that once the thread pool is out of threads, new threads are created only at the rate of one per second (or so).

When you create a `Thread` object explicitly, there's no waiting. They are created and begun immediately. There may be a slightly delay, on the order of dozens of milliseconds, before the thread actually gets its turn to start executing, but otherwise it's effectively instantaneous.

Comment: Surely some of the early tasks should start at least?

Comment: Lacking [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the behavior, it's impossible to say for sure what's going on. I'm just explaining the difference between the secondary tasks/threads. It seems unlikely to me that _no_ primary tasks start before they are all set up, because if that were the case, then the _content_ of those tasks' method wouldn't affect the startup behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks are scheduled using threadpool worker threads.
If you want to bypass the threadpool you can declare your Task as [`LongRunning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) that will start a new thread immediately.

If you need some more information about it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx